# How do I use the data from a .png packed in a .jar as a texture in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, png, textures, lwjgl

So I'm making a basic game in Java using LWJGL. I have a .png file packed in the .jar that obviously cannot be used for textures while it's still inside the .jar. The only way I can think of getting the file out of the .jar is to create an Image object.

I've tried using getResource, but the way I currently have it set up is that it calls on the path to create a FileInputStream (I'm using a PNGDecoder class that takes the PNG's FileInputStream and directly creates the LWJGL Texture), and so it can't exactly read the .png from within the .jar.

Does anyone know how I can make the PNGDecoder happy, or have another way to convert the packed .png to a LWJGL texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PNGDecoder` probably accepts any `InputStream` and not just a `FileInputStream`. Use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` to directly get an `InputStream` of the .png file in the .jar, without the need to extract it first.

Comment: +1 If that decoder requires a FileInputStream instead of a general InputStream, it's stupid.

Comment: The decoder does require an InputStream (not necessarily a FileInputStream), but if I specify it like @hfs mentioned, rather than generate one from getResource, it works like a charm. Thanks a bunch!